# Pre-stimulus baseline removal in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, data-transformation, normalization

I have the following scenario:

- trials were conducted where participants were exposed to multiple stimuli during the course of a trial
- a specific physiological response was continuously recorded during each trial

For every set of stimulation phase response data, I would like to apply baseline removal based on the pre-stimulus data, i.e., data gathered about 500ms before the introduction of the stimulus. My questions is: how can I do that in R? Even a purely theoretical description would be very helpful.